# Update URL of uploaded file in Woocommerce line item

Tags: rest, woocommerce, file-upload

I have a woocommerce site (WP) where the user uploads a number of images when they place their order.  I interact with these orders via a custom backend application that accesses the order/items using the REST API.

I would like to be able to accomplish 2 tasks.  First I need to be able to delete the uploaded file from the backend storage area (using the files URL I would assume) then I need to update the uploaded file record so that I can replace the URL of the uploaded file to a new URL of my creation.

I know there are a few plugins that work in this area but for a number of reasons they are not suitable for my use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something like this.

```
// Initialize WP Filesystem
WP_Filesystem();
global $wp_filesystem;

// Copy the file to a new location
$wp_filesystem->copy($original_file_path, $new_file_path);

 // Update the database record with the new file URL
 global $wpdb;
 $wpdb->update(
 $table_name,
 array('file_url' => $new_file_url),
 array('order_id' => $order_id)
);

// Delete the original file
$wp_filesystem->delete($original_file_path);
```

---

Edit:

Here, the original file is deleted from Amazon S3, a new one is uploaded, and the WooCommerce line item metadata is updated using the REST API.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';  // Required if using Composer for AWS SDK

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

// Initialize AWS S3 client
$s3 = new S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'your_aws_region'
]);

// Delete the original file from S3
$s3->deleteObject([
    'Bucket' => 'your_bucket_name',
    'Key'    => 'your_original_file_key'
]);

// Upload the new file to S3
$result = $s3->putObject([
    'Bucket' => 'your_bucket_name',
    'Key'    => 'your_new_file_key',
    'SourceFile' => 'path/to/your/new/file'
]);

$new_file_url = $result['ObjectURL'];

// Define the order ID and line item ID
$order_id = 'your_order_id_here';
$line_item_id = 'your_line_item_id_here';

// API endpoint
$api_endpoint = "https://yourwebsite.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/{$order_id}";

// Authentication
$consumer_key = 'your_consumer_key_here';
$consumer_secret = 'your_consumer_secret_here';

// Data payload
$data = array(
'line_items' => array(
    array(
    'id' => $line_item_id,
    'meta_data' => array(
        array(
        'key' => 'file_url',
        'value' => $new_file_url,
        ),
    ),
    ),
),
);

// API request arguments
$args = array(
'method' => 'PUT',
'headers' => array(
    'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode($consumer_key . ':' . $consumer_secret),
),
'body' => json_encode($data),
);

// Execute the API request
$response = wp_remote_post($api_endpoint, $args);

// Check for success
if (is_wp_error($response)) {
$error_message = $response->get_error_message();
echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
} else {
echo 'Successfully updated line item metadata.';
}
?>
```

Comment: I was really hoping for a REST API solution.  I'll look into this in the meantime.  The new destination of file will be S3, not sure if wp_filesystem->copy supports that.

Comment: There, I hope that works. And I didn't include the authentication for S3, but I'm guessing you have that handled on your end.

Comment: Was that adequate for your needs?

Comment: In terms of updating the meta data in WP yes it was very helpful.  The images I need to delete were uploaded by a plugin with Woo so I don't have direct access to them to delete them.  The only thing I see is some PHP code working in the Media namespace but nothing in REST.  I'm still looking.